# Using a caret(^) when using Git for Windows in PowerShell

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I'm using git at the command line with PowerShell, and I'm trying to use something like

```
git difftool HEAD^
```

Powershell seems to treat this as if I typed

```
git difftool HEAD
```

so the caret symbol is gone. If I use multiple copies of the caret, I get a weird error:

```
git difftool HEAD^^
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD@set': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

Interestingly, using four carets in a row seems to escape down to one, so `git difftool HEAD^^^^` works as I expect `git difftool HEAD^` to work.

I've tried escaping the caret with single quotes, double quotes, grave accents, nothing seems to help.

Is this a feature of PowerShell, or is my setup wrong somewhere?

Comment: Do you get different results from `git log -n 1 HEAD` and `git log -n 1 HEAD^`?

Comment: No, it is the same as described above -- to get the right behaviour I need to use `git log -n 1 HEAD^^^^`

Comment: I found the problem detailed in my answer below. Changed the title to better reflect the problem.

Comment: Here is HEAD^^ in text, to run .bat in powershell and is echoing and running HEAD^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the problem, and it was with my setup :(

I'm using Git for Windows, which provides `git.exe` in a /bin folder and `git.cmd` in a /cmd folder. `git.cmd` is a batch script which wraps `git.exe` and does some other stuff.

Both of these directories were in my PATH, with /cmd coming first, so when I typed `git`, `git.cmd` was being run. Because this was a batch script the caret could not be used. In the cmd world a caret is escaped by typing two of them (`^^`).

I guess that this was somehow being required twice, so four carets would be escaped down to two, then one (I don't really understand this bit). I also don't understand the error message when two or three carets are used.

## The Lesson Is...

Only use git.exe when using Git for Windows with PowerShell!

Answer (score 1):

The ^ is reserved as the escape character in the cmd shell environment.  You might have better luck using start-process and passing it in the argument list, but I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use ~ instead of ^

git difftool HEAD~

Note that HEAD^^ is the same as HEAD~2

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the caret with a back-tick: `

```
PS C:\>"Hello`^"
Hello^
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use git, this is just just an idea, what if you enclose it in quotes?

```
git difftool "HEAD^"
```

Comment: Yeah I said in the question that I tried that already. Doesn't seem to matter what I enclose it in.