# How to install a specific version of package using Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I am trying to install a specific version of a package using Composer. I tried `composer install` and `composer require` but they are installing the latest version of the package. What if I want an older version?

Comment: have a read on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212381/composer-how-can-i-install-another-dependency-without-updating-old-ones

Answer (score 1137, accepted):

`composer require vendor/package:version`

for example:

`composer require refinery29/test-util:0.10.2`

Comment: what is the function ^ and ~ in version number?

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/1522019

Comment: @DediAnanto please look at this link from npm packages similar interaction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json

Comment: `composer require vendor/package:version --with-all-dependencies` to make sure all of its dependency will be updated.

Answer (score 270):

Add double quotes to use `"^" caret operator` in version number.

```
composer require middlewares/whoops "^0.4"
```

Comment: I don't see a point in time where you could pass [package name](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.0.0/doc/03-cli.md#require) and [version](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.0.0/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php#L41) as two separate arguments.

Comment: @x-yuri passing package name and version as separate arguments works for me using composer 1.5.1

Comment: While technically this isn't the "correct" answer for the OP's question, this is probably more useful for most people.

Comment: If you're using PowerShell and Git for Windows the caret needs to be escaped twice: "^^^^0.4" or just use Git Bash or cmd.exe.  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600549/using-a-caret-when-using-git-for-windows-in-powershell#_=_

Answer (score 57):

As @alucic mentioned, use:

```
composer require vendor/package:version
```

or you can use:

```
composer update vendor/package:version
```

You should probably review [this StackOverflow post about differences between composer install and composer update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052195/what-are-the-differences-between-composer-update-and-composer-install).

Related to question about version numbers, you can review [Composer documentation on versions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md), but here in short:

- Tilde Version Range (**~**) - ~1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <**1.3.0**
- Caret Version Range (**^**) - ^1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <**2.0.0**

So, with **Tilde** you will get automatic updates of patches but minor and major versions will not be updated. However, if you use **Caret** you will get patches and minor versions, but you will not get major (breaking changes) versions.

Tilde Version is considered a "safer" approach, but if you are using reliable dependencies (well-maintained libraries) you should not have any problems with Caret Version (because minor changes should not be breaking changes.

Comment: The `composer update vendor/package:version` won't work.

Answer (score 38):

just use php composer.phar require

For example :

```
php composer.phar require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 3.0
```

Also available with install.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Comment: For the record, adding custom constraints is *not* available with `install` - only with `require`. If you were hoping to switch to a specific version and check-in your `composer.lock` file, you can, but you'd have to use `composer require` and then revert the change to `composer.json` afterwards.

Comment: Version as a separate argument? Was that ever available?

Answer (score 21):

Suppose you want to install Laravel Collective. It's currently at version 6.x but you want version 5.8.  You can run the following command:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.8.0"
```

A good example is shown here in the documentation:
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.5/html

Comment: Please share more details - the version constraint `^5.8.0` would not restrict Composer to use a specific version, but still allow multiple versions to be installed

Answer (score 4):

In your `composer.json`, you can put:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/package": "version"
    }
}
```

then run `composer install` or `composer update` from the directory containing `composer.json`.  Sometimes, for me, composer is hinky, so I'll start with `composer clear-cache; rm -rf vendor; rm composer.lock` before `composer install` to make sure it's getting fresh stuff.

---

Of course, as the other answers point out you can run the following from the terminal:

```sh
composer require vendor/package:version
```

---

And on versioning:
- [Composer's official versions article](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md)
- [Ecosia Search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=php+composer+versioning)

Answer (score 4):

I tried to require a development branch from a different repository and not the latest version and I had the same issue and non of the above worked for me :(

after a while I saw in the documentation that in cases of dev branch you need to require with a 'dev-' prefix to the version and the following worked perfectly.

```
composer require [vendorName]/[packageName]:dev-[gitBranchName]
```