# Is there a way to limit a vendor's package version requirements

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using the acelaya/zf2-acqrcode package (v0.2.0) It requires "endroid/qrcode": ">=1.2.0", (meaning everything higher than or equal to 1.2.0)

Currently the latest version of the "endroid/qrcode" package = v3.2.12

The acelaya/zf2-acqrcode package (v0.2.0) uses a function that doesn't exist anymore in endroid/qrcode versions > 1.9.3

Is there any way I can tell composer not to install a version of the endroid/qrcode package higher than 1.9.3?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer

Comment: I can't set the acelaya/zf2-acqrcode package requirements .. Your suggestion will only work for packages that I require for my application. (meaning: If I would require the endroid/qrcode package in my project composer.json file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can restrict the package versions by using the `~` operator in composer.json. More Information on that can be found [Here](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/tilde-and-caret-constraints/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but i'm talking about a 3rd party package. I'm not in control of the acelaya/zf2-acqrcode source code.

Comment: Yes I am assuming that the third party package is in packagist.org.

Comment: @mattyh88 Yes, but `composer` will take into account the requirements from your `composer.json` file and the `composer.json` of the vendor.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can control the version of the dependencies in your composer.json as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to lock the `endroid/qrcode` dependency to `1.9.3`. Sub dependencies *will* adhere to this and honour the fact you've locked `acelaya/zf2-acqrcode`.

*Note: this will only fail when another dependency requires `>1.9.3` of `endroid/qrcode`*

```
{
    "require": {
        "endroid/qrcode": "1.9.3",
        "acelaya/zf2-acqrcode": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

Run the command following command:

```
/path/to/composer.phar require endroid/qrcode:1.9.3
```

Here's the output of the above required dependencies:

```
$ composer install                                                     
Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Package operations: 18 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (3.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-loader (2.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-eventmanager (3.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-view (2.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing container-interop/container-interop (1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-servicemanager (3.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-validator (2.10.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-uri (2.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-http (2.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-router (3.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-config (3.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-modulemanager (2.8.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-mvc (3.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/options-resolver (v3.4.11): Loading from cache
  - Installing endroid/qrcode (1.9.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing acelaya/zf2-acqrcode (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
```

Comment: if you are not really requiring this third party library i would not add it to the require part. maybe you could add it to the conflict section in composer? and anyway report this bug to the maintainer of acelaya/zf2-acqrcode

Comment: That's the preferred approach, but this will get around that issue, especially as the OP isn't a maintainer of said package.

Comment: adding it to his composer.json conflict section will get the OP around that issue

Comment: Then suggest that as an answer.