# php: how to install a package using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, mpdf

I'm totally new to composer ;-)

I try to install mPDF 7.1 on my localhost (ubuntu 16.04) with composer.

1.) I installed composer 1.6.5.

2.) Downloaded mPDF 7.1 (https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases) and unzipped folder to hdd.

3.) Open terminal in mpdf-7.1.0 folder and typed `$ composer require mpdf/mpdf` to start process

--> Error message is thrown:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package mpdf/mpdf No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

So I don't know what's the problem is and don't find any help searching the web. Can you help me?

Andreas

**EDIT**: I tried also:

`$ composer require mpdf/mpdf:7.1.0` and

`$ composer require mpdf/mpdf "^7.1.0"`

throw same error message...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a specific version of package using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer)

Comment: Not really a duplicate of that one. This one is more about an error due to running composer install incorrectly (in the wrong folder), and doesn't have much to do with specific versions (despite the error message).

Comment: Make sure composer is globally installed. Try `sudo composer require vendor/pacakge` in case of any problem.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to download mPDF, that is what composer will do for you.

Do this:

1. Create an empty directory in which you will use mPDF

   - It should not have a parent with composer.json file already present, no matter the level
2. Run `composer require mpdf/mpdf` in the new directory

   - If there is a composer.json in one of parent directories, decline the prompt `No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at <parent>`
   - Composer will now install mPDF and create autoloading files in the current directory
3. Require `vendor/autoload.php` in a PHP file
4. Done, you now can use mPDF in the file.

Comment: No composer.json in current directory

Comment: @BMX Lacking context. Maybe you can try searching the web for composer basics and then submit a separate question here if you still have problems.

Comment: thats what the cmd will display if you try to do what you answered there. "No composer.json in current directory"

Comment: explain it in a better way so people dont get confused.

Comment: Confused how? Be more specific. I've just followed the 4 points and there were no problems. Not even any `No composer.json in current directory` message, only notice `./composer.json has been created`.

Comment: I also followed similar 4 steps and encountered same 'No composer.json' error @BMX faced. I still haven't been able to overcome it. I use PHP 7.3.14-5+ubuntu18.04.1

Comment: after running "composer require mpdf/mpdf" command i get this message " No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at /data/projects/beanstalk/btl-v1? [Y,n]? ".

Comment: I followed the instructions and mPDF was perfectly installed. I wonder why this answer was not accepted.

Comment: The prompt with mentioned message is shown when there is a composer.json file in one of parent directories. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure composer is installed globally. It works fine so.
2. Create an empty directory in which you will use any package, for example, **mPDF**
3. Run `composer require mpdf/mpdf` in the new directory

   - The command above does not work use `sudo composer require mpdf/mpdf`
4. If you want to specify any version of your package

   - Then specify thus `composer require vendor/package:version`
   - For example: `composer require mpdf/mpdf:7.1.0`
5. Composer will now install **mPDF** and create autoload.php in the vendor directory for autoloading files
6. **mPDF** installation is **done**. **Now create a php file called `mpdf.php` for example, in same deirectory**.
7. Require `vendor/autoload.php` in that PHP file.

Directory structure should be where you installed **mPDF**:

```
vendor
composer.json
composer.lock
mpdf.php
```

And the mpdf.php file is as follows:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: composer to be run in windows. How to install mdf  on server .. web server or website ..I downloaded mpdf-8.1.0 there is no vendor directory

Comment: @user1526780 What I did to install Mpdf on web server: Follow the above steps to install Mpdf in a directory on your windows filesystem. Then use FTP to upload that directory to your webserver.  Finally, put the command "use Mpdf\Mpdf;" at the top of your php script on the server.  This worked for me.