# html purifier specific version in a composer

Tags: centos, composer-php, htmlpurifier

I want to put html purifier into the composer with a specific version 4.11.0

I have tried all methods in the link below (except the last one)

[How to install a specific version of package using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer)

Is there a way to put the specific version of the html purifier in the composer without typing 
composer require ezyang/htmlpurifier ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the line ...

```
"require": {
  "[..]": "[..]",
  "ezyang/htmlpurifier": "4.11.0"
}
```

to your `composer.json`. Then run:

```sh
composer update ezyang/htmlpurifier --with-dependencies
```