# How to install Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel for laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm working on a project with laravel 5.4. I'm editing an old project and adding some features. But I'm facing a problem with installing excel package that is suitable to this version.  I think Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel v:2.1 could be suitable but how can I install an old version of Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel since the last version is is 3.1 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a specific version of package using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
```

in composer and re-install composer packages

or run

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel:2.1.0
```

[image]

Comment: @Muhammed how can I re-install composer packages ?

Comment: @Developer composer install

Comment: It seems that it won't work with this version mine.It wasn't installed. It seems that even "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0" doen't support this version .

Comment: @Developer check your PHP version

Comment: if I run composer update, will that affect anything in my project? @Muhammed

Comment: @Muhammed PHP 7.2.24-

Comment: @Developer that will update your package to latest version

Comment: @Developer see, I have update answer by Image. According to that you must be using PHP 7.0 or less then 7.0

Answer (score 1):

In addition to verifying PHP version, it seems better to run

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel:2.1.*
```

For example, Laravel 5.4 support starts in [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel 2.1.10](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/releases/tag/2.1.10) and Laravel 5.5 support in [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel 2.1.21](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/releases/tag/2.1.21)