# How can I use Drush 9 (instead of Drush 10) in my Drupal 8 DDEV-Local project?

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8, drush, ddev

Using ddev I created a webserver locally and I have a Drupal 8 project with drush 10, but I need drush 9.
How can I change the version of drush in the project?
Thanks so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a specific version of package using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer)

Comment: I used the command "composer require drush/drush:9"  in the home directory.
I run the <code>drush --version command and the answer was "Drush Launcher Version: 0.6.0 Drush Commandline Tool 9.0.0."
I run the command in the webroot and e restitusce Launcher Version: 0.6.0 Drush Commandline Tool 10.0.0

Comment: Please update your question accordingly. And when you are inside the container run `cd web && ../vendor/drush/drush/drush --version` instead.

Comment: I run the command <code>cd web && ../vendor/drush/drush/drush --version</code> and the answer was <code>Drush Commandline Tool 10.2.2</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @leymannx says in the comments, this isn't really a ddev question, it's a composer question, but it's easy.

`ddev composer require "drush/drush:^9"` will get the most recent Drush 9 version.

But I should mention that it's unlikely that you actually need Drush 9, Drush 10 is what most people are using with Drupal 8 and 9.