# laravel installing older package version

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install this package https://packagist.org/packages/ultraware/roles for laravel 5.3.
simply applying `composer require ultraware/roles` doesn't work as it is not compatible with laravel 5.3 and i guess I should install an older version of the package. How can i do it. When i try to run 
`composer require ultraware/roles^1.7.*` I get:

Could not find a matching version of package

How can i install version 1.7 of this package?

Comment: As you can see on https://packagist.org/packages/ultraware/roles#1.7.0, that version is five years old - are you sure you want to use that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a specific version of package using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want version `1.7` of this package to be installed, looks like `5.3.1` is a version compatible with Laravel 5.3.

**Note:**

> **This package is abandoned and no longer maintained.**

If you still want to install a specific version of this package use the following:

```
composer require ultraware/roles "5.3.1"
```

Comment: Thanks. So to install a specific version we just put it between " "?

Comment: Either that or I think `composer require "ultraware/roles:5.3.1"` would also work