# sonata admin-bundle in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm using the following command: **composer requires sonata-project/admin-bundle** but it is installing the latest version of sonata which is not compatible with Symfony 3.4
i am getting the following:
Problem 1
- Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle ^3.73 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[3.73.0].
- sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.73.0 requires symfony/asset ^4.4 -> no matching package found.

How can I fix that? a way to choose which sonata version i want to install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a specific version of package using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command to install the chosen version:

`composer requires sonata-project/admin-bundle:3.x`

Comment: For some reason this doesn't install SonataFormBundle or SonataTwigBundle even though the docs say to add them as bundles to register. https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/3.x/getting_started/installation/