# How can I fix this error? "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

command:

```
composer require laravel/scout -W
```

error:

```
Using version ^8.4 for laravel/scout
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/scout --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 8.2.*, found laravel/framework[v8.2.0] but it conflicts with another require.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

this is my composer.json file. someone asked me to add it, so I added it.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "8.2.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have laravel version 5.8 and I couln't find correct solution for this.
unfortunately, I was not able to find older version numbers which I can install.

I wasn't really able to install any other requires too, for example, newer version of laravel/framework.

aslo, composer require laravel/scout -W doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a specific version of package using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer)

Comment: please attach `composer.json` i think conflicts for requires laravel/framework 8.2.* in composer

Comment: I added composer.json file