# Is it possible to run composer update command without actually updating anything

Tags: composer-php

I'm using [cweagans/composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) to apply patches to my project (Magento 2). To minimise changes, I'd like composer to only apply the patch and not update any dependencies to the latest versions.

Patching is triggered at the end of a `composer update` command, and the new extra.patches section in the composer file lists patches which should be applied to packages. As far as I understand, the `composer update` will try to update all dependencies.

I think I can reduce the behaviour by doing a `composer update [vendor]/[package]` where `[vendor]/[package]` is the package I want to patch.

Is there any way of running the `composer update` command without triggering an update.

Comment: Did you tried `composer update --lock`?

Comment: You can get the answer in here bro
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914114/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-using-composer

Comment: @rob006 I've not tried that but according to the official docs, `--lock` only updates the lock file hash to suppress warning about the lock file being out of date, which doesn't sound like it would work, but I'll give it a go anyway.

Comment: @PhạmThếHùng all the answers on that page talk about `require`, not `update`. I do not believe that specifying a version with require will lock the dependency versions.

Comment: `composer update --lock` should already do this, but you may also use `composer install` after `composer update --lock` - `cweagans/composer-patches` should reinstall package if it detects different patch settings between installed version and `composer.lock`.

Comment: @Dom composer install may be the one you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--dry-run` option of `composer update` command.

Look at options section of this doc https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u

Answer (score 0):

`composer install` worked for me , thanks [Is it possible to run composer update command without actually updating anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65861031/is-it-possible-to-run-composer-update-command-without-actually-updating-anything/77020001#comment116456737_65861031)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `composer update --lock`.
I used it a lot after changes of patches in the composer.json and making hash in composer.lock look good.