# I can't install spatie/laravel-sitemap on Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm getting this error when installing:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - spatie/laravel-sitemap[5.9.0, ..., 5.9.2] require illuminate/support ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ...,
> 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
> - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-sitemap ^5.9 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-sitemap[5.9.0, 5.9.1, 5.9.2].
>
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version
> constraint, e.g. "composer require spatie/laravel-sitemap:*" to figure
> out if any version is installable, or "composer require
> spatie/laravel-sitemap:^2.1" if you know which you need.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

Comment: Maybe you should consider updating Laravel? v5.6 is unsupported since three years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just

```
composer require spatie/laravel-sitemap:*
#                                       ^
```

Composer will figure out if any version (**`*`**) is installable (thanks to *dependency resolution*, compare [*Dependency Hell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) etc.).

You can also leave the star (`*`) out, as it poses some problems in the shell/command interpreter. Example:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-sitemap
```

---

See as well: [*How to install a specific version of package using Composer?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40914114)