# how can i use youtube php api with older version of php?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I tried to run a website code that uses the Youtube API PHP library, but even though the server that I tried to run the code on is using PHP 7.3.3(which, google says is compatible) it's giving me an error that I say that I need to use PHP 8.1.0 or higher, and I can't use a newer version because the website that I trying to develop is using PHP 7.3.3.

I tried to search for a solution to his problem, but I couldn't find i solution to this problem.

btw, I'm using composer, is that could be the problem?

Comment: Show us the exact error message

Comment: ok, here is the error message:
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".

Comment: Maybe you need to use a slightly older version of the youtube library then

Comment: can you please explain me how to do that?

Comment: You should be able to ask composer to install a specific version.

Comment: ok, but how do  i do that, and how i can check if it was done correctly?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=composer+install+specific+version

Comment: i tried to serch it on the internet before, but i still don't understend how am i supposed to do that.

Comment: So https://stackoverflow.com/a/41703068/5947043 (the first link in my results) didn't help you?

Comment: not so much, because i don't understand how to implement the solutions that people has suggested on the comments of that post. 
can you please explain me in details how am i supposed to do that?

Comment: You run the command as shown, but replace the name of the package and the version number you want to install, in the places shown in the example. There's not much more to say.

Comment: ho, ok.
thank you for your help and support.